# Export problem for the class only written in cpp

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, dll, entity

I have two projects, one is an executable (app), and the other is a static/shared library (lib).

In the lib project, my structure looks like this:

```cpp
// lib proj interface
class Entity
{

};

class EntitySystem
{
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class EventSystem
{
public:
    static bool register_update_system(IEntitySystem* system){...}
    void update()
    {
        // for each entity, call system->update(entity);
    }
};
```

Then I only implement systems in the .cpp files and use static methods to register my update function, for example:

```cpp
// timersystem.cpp
class TimerSystem: public EntitySystem
{
public:
    void update(TimerEntity& entity) override
    {
        ...
    }
};

bool _ = EventSystem::register_update_system(new TimerSystem());
```

However, after building and running the app, the line `bool _ = EventSystem::register_update_system(new TimerSystem());` doesn't seem to execute. In other words, the TimerSystem is not correctly registered in the EventSystem in the app project. How can I resolve this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: If the registration code is in a static library your linker can eliminate the registration because the executable does not call it. If it is a shared library it won't do that. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873731/object-registration-in-static-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873731/object-registration-in-static-library)

Comment: In the case of the dll failing to work, does the dll export any symbols? If not maybe it's eliminated because the linker determines that nothing in the dll can be used. I am guessing for this issue. I do use factories in dlls but they always export some symbol.

Comment: @drescherjm wouldn't the linker fail to resolve the symbol if it was eliminated instead of discarding a function call ? (genuinely asking)

Comment: The linker can determine that the symbol is not needed and remove it.

Comment: `bool _ = EventSystem::register_update_system(new TimerSystem());` can be completely removed by the linker eliminating the call to EventSystem::register_update_system()